# Making a pointer to an array of structures

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, struct

Having difficulty solving the below challenge.
My attempt is the code below the struct. I'm not quite clear as to how I would save the individual entries to the array as when I attempt to use a bracket to index each entry into the loop i'm met with an error.
Is there something I'm missing or overthinking?

Use the Time structure to define and dynamically allocate memory for an array of 10 times. After that return the allocated memory back to the operating system

```
struct Time {
        int hrs;
        int min;
        int sec; 
    };    

Time *t2 = new Time[10];

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    cout << "Enter time in format HHMMSS "<< i + 1 << ": ";
    cin >> t2->hrs>>t2->min>>t2->sec;
    
}
cout << setw(8) << "INDEX" << setw(10) << "Time" << endl;
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    cout << setw(8) << i << setw(10) << t2->hrs <<":"<< t2->min<<":"<<t2->sec<< endl;
}

delete[] t2;
```

Comment: `t2->hrs` This refers to `hrs` in the `Time` pointed to by `t2`, which is the very first element in the array that you allocated. Use `t2[i].hrs` instead to refer to `hrs` in the `i`'th element of the array.

Comment: That did it @dxiv. Thanks man. This has been bugging me for a bit. Was trying to index the wrong value.